# What does 決まった人たち mean in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

> 「**決まった人たち**が『なんでそんなしゃべり方なの』ってずっと言ってくる」 「いつも笑わない人たちが発表のときに急に笑い出した」([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/web_tokushu/2018_0828.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_003))

'People that are decided/selected' doesn't make sense in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has little to nothing with "deciding" or "making a decision" as far as translation is concerned.

「決{き}まった」 here means "fixed", "regular", "unchanging", "same", etc.

Thus, 「決まった人たちが『なんでそんなしゃべり方{かた}なの』ってずっと言ってくる」 means:

> "The same group of people keep asking me 'Why do you speak like that?'"

It is always the same guys who do it.

This usage of 「決まった」 is actually very common.

I often say 「決まったお店{みせ}でしかステーキは食{た}べない。」, which means "I only eat steaks at a few fixed restaurants (and nowhere else)."

Answer (score 0):

きまる may also mean "the same"

Examples:
毎朝決まった道を通る。
Every morning, I pass the same street.

買う店が決まっている。
The shop I buy is always the same.

きまる【決（ま）る／極まる】: 変わらないで同じである。一定している。
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/53852/meaning/m1u/決まる/](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/53852/meaning/m1u/%E6%B1%BA%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8B/)

So 決まった人たち mean "the same people".